# Does cauterize reduce all types of heal?

Tags: paladins

From the description of the [cauterize item](https://paladins.gamepedia.com/Cauterize) :

> Your Weapon shots reduce the effect of healing on your target by 30%/60%/90% for 1.5s

I know it reduces the heal from other player abilities, but does it reduce all kind of heals ? Here are all the sources of heal I could think about, does anyone know if Cauterize works on them ?

- Heal from *Life Rip* (item or abilities)
- Self Healing (like Buck *Recovery*)
- Heal from cards (like Inara *Caretaker*)
- Bonus healing from *Rejuvenate* item
- Heal from *Kill to heal* item

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cauterise effects all forms of healing. There are calculators out there that can help out there including [my one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p5w6Upe4lIB9Ezi-fyhRlYGgZMdYo1hX7TQu7jQMGFc/edit?usp=drivesdk), a friend and I also spent some time a while ago testing [cauterise Vs life rip](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14tXTl1L-BFGs_p61NggZMnkjfvRugZlNl24yR90yXR4/edit?usp=drivesdk)